# Server-side show/hide of HTML without producing additional markup

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, webforms

Using something like this to show/hide certain markup:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="MyPanel">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    ...
</asp:Panel>
```

It is rendered out as something like:

```
<div>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    ...
</div>
```

Now I want to have the ability to show/hide the `MyPanel` server-side but do not want the surrounding `div` to be rendered.

I *could* do something like:

```
<% if (MyCondition) { %>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    ...
<% } %>
```

but this looks rather cluttered to me.

Or I *could* do something like:

```
<li runat="server" ID="C1">...</li>
<li runat="server" ID="C2">...</li>
...
```

but this would require all "root" controls to have a `runat=server` attribute which produces a lot of code and looks cluttered, too, to me.

**My question:**

Is there a way to tell  the `Panel` control to not produce any markup itself? Or is there another control to use for my purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've ended up by using the [`Literal` control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol).

With this control, I could write something like:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <asp:Literal runat="server" Visible="false">
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
    </asp:Literal>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

which results in this:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

And I also could write something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <asp:Literal runat="server" Visible="true">
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
    </asp:Literal>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

which results in something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

So this is exactly what I wanted: A server-control that allows me to show/hide multiple HTML markup tags without rendering any additional markup.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want div generated against Panel then you can make the ul runat server and assign this control some id and show hide it with visible attribute in code behind.

```
<li id="myUl" runat="server">

</li>
```

The panel allows to have scroll bar that are actually achieved through div wont be there by using ul directly.

Comment: Thanks, I know. The structure is more complex. Will update my example.

Comment: You have many controls in Panel as you showed in OP. You want to show hide with single statement without having any container?

Comment: Yes, exactly this way.

Comment: This is contradiction that all controls should be treated as a unit without having any relation i.e is same parent like panel or div in current scenario. Can you explain why you do not want Parent div or Panel?

Comment: Reason is that this is a part of a longer `UL` list where I only want several `LI` elements to be hidden but not all. Placing a `DIV` around those does make invalid markup. I've updated my question again.

Comment: You can control the visibility of li through css classes as well. I can't understand why placing div to wrap the UL make html invalid.

Comment: Because I do not want to make the whole `UL` invisible but only some of the `LI`s inside the `UL`.

Comment: You can control visibility through common class if you do not want to do it with ids